# OpenCV: Finding correct frame rate of video file

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture, frame-rate

I am attempting to calculate the frame rate and the total number of frames in a .mov video file using OpenCV3 and Python 3. I am using OpenCV's cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT to get my total number of frames and I am using OpenCV's cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS to get the frame rate. The issue is that I am getting inaccurate values from these functions. My program is telling me that the total number of frames in my video is 115 and that the frame rate is 30 fps. However, I recorded the video with an iPhone 7 using 60 fps. So my frame rate should be 60 and my total number of frames should be 230. I also get a frame rate of 30 fps when I read from a video that was recorded at 120 fps. Can anyone explain why I am getting these values?

```
import cv2

video_cap = cv2.VideoCapture('videos/SixtyFPS.mov')
video_cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)

# The following method for counting the total number of frames in the video is 
# inaccurate
number_of_frames = int(video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
print("The total number of frames is: " + str(number_of_frames))

# The following methdd for calculating the video's frame rate is inaccurate
fps = int(video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
print("The frame rate is: " + str(fps))
```

Comment: Have you also enabled 60 FPS video export from your phone? (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205346)

Comment: I actually think that this is the problem. The videos were recorded at 60 fps on my friend's iPhone 7 and then they were sent to me. I was not aware that when the videos were sent that they got compressed to 30 fps. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.